# Swift: captureOutput not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I am working on my first Swift app which was going fine until I got stuck here. Please take a look at the code below.

```
//
//  CameraFrames.swift
//  Explore
//
//  Created by Kushagra Agarwal on 13/08/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Kushagra Agarwal. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import AVFoundation


protocol CameraFramesDelegate {
    func processCameraFrames(sampleBuffer : CMSampleBufferRef)
}


class CameraFrames : NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var delegate : CameraFramesDelegate?

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession();
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        // Capture the session with High settings preset
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

        self.captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo);

        // Because the old error handling method is deprecated
        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice));
        } catch {
            print("Error in getting input from camera");
        }

        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);

        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput();

        var outputQueue : dispatch_queue_t?
        outputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("outputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: outputQueue)

        output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true;
        output.videoSettings = nil;

        captureSession.addOutput(output);

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        captureSession.startRunning();
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didDropSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        print("frame dropped")
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        print("frame received")
    }
}
```

The preview shows up fine on the phone but the `captureOutput` is never called for some reason. I looked at some old SO threads, but none helped me resolve this issue. Any idea what can be the reason behind it?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I have a view controller in which I am previewing the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` layer, which works well. I have a feeling that the issue is somewhere in setting up the `outputQueue` but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I tried moving this code to my viewcontroller where I was displaying the previewLayer, and it worked! `captureOutput` is now being called. Still not sure what was the problem with the about approach. Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: did you find out why?